# "self" is safer than calling an object without it ?

Tags: objective-c

I have seen both ways from different programmers.

- **[[self object] method]**
- **[object method]**

Some other just use **[self.object method]** instead of **[[self object] method]**.

Does self give me a safety about not calling other objects ?
I think second way is more readable.

What should I use ?

Comment: Is it possible to describe a little bit more clearer as to the context that these "objects" are being used?  Are these objects properties?  For example you would have [self.object method] if you were calling a property from it's own class, while [object method] is usually calling a method on an object.

Comment: I'm actually generally speaking, but let's say I have a "Work class" with a property of "Employee *john". I initialized "john" and i'm writing a method of Work Class where I want to use a method of Employee object, like [john setSalary:10]. I have something like that on my mind. Another example would be just a textField object. [textField setIntValue:10]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's up to you. They are just different styles of programming. However, if your getter method does more than just return `object`, calling `self.object` or `[self object]` (which are the same thing) every time could be less efficient.

for example:

```
- (NSObject *) object {
  // some random code here
  return _object;
}
```

consider these two examples:

```
NSObject *obj = [self object];
[[self object] method];
```

vs.

```
NSObject *obj = [self object];
[obj method];
```

The second method could be more efficient, since the "random code" in the getter method is only executed once, whereas in the first example it is executed twice (each time `[self object]` is called).

Comment: Don't say it's less efficient before you have checked that. Put it in a loop, run it a billion times and check which of the two is faster.

Comment: I am simply saying that it could be less efficient in some scenarios where the getter is executing more commands than simply returning the object. It's not always less efficient, but in certain conditions it could be.

Comment: I created a project to check what you said Michael. I synthesized a "Person*" object and I also created a getter for this object with an NSLog as random code. I tried both ways. When I used [[self person]method] NSLog in getter returned 1 output but when I used [person method] it didn't use the getter at all. So were right ;)

Answer (score 0):

I personally use [object method].  However, by using [self.object method] or [[self object] method], you are guaranteeing that there are no name collisions.  I think this is really just a matter of personal preference.  The one thing that keeps catching me is when I'm using a property that I synthesized using _object syntax, and I keep trying to do [object method] instead of [_object method].  So, it's up to you.